# Scope update after $rootScope event and Promise is not reflected in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Seen a couple of people having similar issues but the usual scope.$apply doesn't work for me ($digest is already in progress). Banging my head today.

Please find a simplified but full version of my directive below.

1. initialize() sets myValue to its initial value.
2. $rootScope event is catched.
3. promise is being resolved.
4. $localStorage is updated
5. console.log(myValue) delivers the correct value.

But my **view isn't updated**. What's going on?!

```js
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('myDirective', myDirective);

  function myDirective($rootScope, $localStorage, MyPromise, MyService) {
    var linkFunction = function (scope, element, attributes) {

      scope.myValue = null;

      $rootScope.$on('someEvent', function (event, data) {

        MyPromise().get({}, function (result) {
          $localStorage.result = result;
          scope.myValue = MyService.getFromLocalStorageAndReturnStuff();
          console.log(scope.myValue);
        });
      });

      initialize();

      function initialize() {

        scope.myValue = MyService.getFromLocalStorageAndReturnStuff();

      }
    };


    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      transclude: true,
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        someProperty: '=myProperty'
      },
      link: linkFunction,
      templateUrl: 'myTemplate.html'
    };
  }
})();
```

```html
{{myValue}}
```

Comment: try to clear the cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's working for me is that I have an external scope property (scope.someProperty) which is changing as well when my event occurs.

Watching on it does change the scope which is reflected in the view.

I am aware that this is not a perfect solution if one really has to react on some event but I wanted to provided my solution for this in case it might be helpful for anyone else.

If someone can provide an answer to the real issue I am happy to accept his answer.

```js
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('myDirective', myDirective);

  function myDirective($rootScope, $localStorage, MyPromise, MyService) {
    var linkFunction = function (scope, element, attributes) {

      scope.myValue = null;

      scope.$watch('someProperty', function(newVal){
      
        if(newVal!==null){
          MyPromise().get({}, function (result) {
             $localStorage.result = result;
             scope.myValue = MyService.getFromLocalStorageAndReturnStuff();
          });
        }
        
      });
      
      initialize();

      function initialize() {

      }
    };


    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      transclude: true,
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        someProperty: '=myProperty'
      },
      link: linkFunction,
      templateUrl: 'myTemplate.html'
    };
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Link function doesn't watch model changes, Hence do the variable set inside the applyAsync Function

```
scope.$applyAsync(function(){
//set here
});
```

Comment: tried to call 'scope.myValue = MyService.getFromLocalStorageAndReturnStuff();' within the $applyAsync. has no effect, neither an exception nor view change.

Comment: try calling scope.$apply after the set,remove applyAsync, also try not isolating scope

Comment: thanks, but see my comment, I already tried scope.$apply - but i am already in a digest cycle.

Comment: Use the controller scope, try not isolating scope